# Java heap space kotlin and IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I'm trying to read a big cvs file (3500000 records) with IntelliJ Idea and Kotlin on a console application, but i have a problem with the heap spece:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

[img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40bYY.png)

I tried to increase the heap size to different values like 2048MB or E.G. 10000MB but it does't work and i'm not able to find a solution.

```
data class  Product(
val year: Int,
val month: Int,
val cod_product: Int,
val unit: Int,
val country: Int,
val uf: String,
val transport: Int,
val revenue: Int,
val quantity: Int,
val weight: Int,
val price: Int
```

)

And i'm using `var products: MutableList<Product> = ArrayList()` to store the data

Comment: You can`t load a big file in memory, instead of sending as a String to the server you should send it as a octet-stream and buffer the file reading/sending to the server, gonna need some retry and resume policy as well

Comment: Or if you not trying to send, use the same buffer strategy reading each line as requested and show only the values that you need in the screen, if you plan to do search on values try to pre-load the values to sqlite and run your queries from there

Comment: I didn't specify that i'm doing a console application and not a mobile application

Comment: The buffer strategy should work too, you need to explain why you need the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: I need the whole file loaded because i would like to manipulate the data with map, filter and reduce functions to extract some useful information. I know that kotlin is not the best language to do that but i have to use it

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have the whole thing in memory in order to map, filter, and reduce.  I'd strongly suggest doing your processing ‘on-the-fly’ as you read each line from the file, without storing anything but your running totals or other intermediate results.  That should handle files of _any_ size, without taking much memory; it's also likely to be far more efficient.  You may be able to use Kotlin's [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html); even if not, that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Where did you change heap size?

Comment: I changed the size on help-> Change memory settings

Comment: Please try to add VM options in your run configuration: "-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m". Modify the value size according to the size of your PC memory.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding this lines into the main gradle of the project (not module) inside allprojects -> repositories

```
tasks.withType(org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.tasks.BaseKtLintCheckTask).configureEach {
    it.workerMaxHeapSize.set("512m")
}
```